# How do you fetch or insert rows in batches using ODBC? ( in C or C++ )

Tags: c++, c, odbc

I am trying to understand which ODBC functions to call and how to call 
them in order to fetch rows in batches or insert rows in batches ( inserts that use bind variables not just an array of insert statements ).

I can fetch one row at a time by calling these functions in order

```
SQLBindParameter
SQLExecute
SQLFetch
```

Also if doing inserts / updates I can do one row at a time by calling these functions

```
SQLBindParameter
SQLExecute
```

What I don't know is what I need to change in these calls in order to:

1) Fetch rows in batches e.g. 150 rows per batch 
2) Insert several rows per SQLExcecute call e.g. 150 rows per call

Short contained examples ( not necessarily compilable since ODBC progs tend to be long .. so ignore setup/initialization, ignore error checking ) demonstrating how this is done would be helpful. Or a pointer to a comprehensible open source code that is doing this sort of thing

Comment: Database reading/writing will be orders of magnitude more expensive than the minor function call overhead of calling SQLBindParameter/SQLExecute a bunch of times.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I know odbc and other propratery apis do support batch operations.
I just don't know how it is done using odbc. In Java for example they have methods like
PreparedStatement.addBatch()
PreparedStatement.executeBatch()

Comment: That's because Java's JNI interface to C is very expensive. So the fewer native calls, the better. That isn't the case when you're programming in C or C++.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I thought one of the advantages of batch operations is the reduction of network traffic.
You affect more rwows per trip by using the batch mode whenever is is supported. 
The advantage would accrue regardless of the language you are using.

Comment: @user754425, you're correct.  If your database is nonlocal, the reduction in network latency involved with multiple trips to and from the server can make batch mode ODBC operations extremely valuable for performance.

Answer (score 3):

The following article tells you how to send rows of parameters in one go:

http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc_odbc_bridge/performance_white_paper.html#3_1_2

Basically, you need to search for SQLSetStmtAttr and SQL_ATTR_PARAMSET_SIZE.

To fetch multiple rows in one go see http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/odbc-tutorial-fetching-results.html

Search for SQL_ATTR_ROW_ARRAY_SIZE.

Answer (score 2):

There are two self contained examples of how to perform array binding on this site
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709287(v=vs.85).aspx 
Also DB2 client ships with several example code some of which show how to do array binding both for inserts and selects

Answer (score 1):

Here is an excellent article from IBM Developerworks that might answer some of your questions about the ODBC architecture:

[ODBC programming using Apache Derby](https://web.archive.org/web/20110130053447/http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0409kartha/index.html) (available via the Wayback Machine)

One of the main "tricks" for optimizing network traffic with an ODBC connection is how you define your cursor:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131453.aspx

'Hope that helps .. PSM